# Spectral norm of banded binary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ defined as $M_{ij}=1$ if $|i-j|\leq k$, and $0$ otherwise.

Is it true that $\|M\|_2\leq O(k)$?

I have shown that $\|M\|_2\leq O(k^{3/2})$, by decomposing the matrix $M$ into a sum of k block-diagonal matrices, each with spectral norm $O(\sqrt{k})$.

Comment: Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could edit your post to answer any of the following questions. How did you come across this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Note that because $M$ is symmetric, its spectral norm is equal to its spectral radius (maximal absolute value of an eigenvalue). It follows that
$$
\|M\|_2 \leq \|M\|_\infty \leq 2k + 1 = O(k),
$$
where $\|M\|_\infty$ denotes the [induced $\infty$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_cases).

Equivalently, we could apply the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) to reach the same conclusion.